# Product filter output is only error echo. Ajax, PHP

Tags: php, ajax, filter, product

I have problem with this product filter. Problem could be with implode() or with `IN ('{$platforma_filter}')`

Every time it outputs only my `echo No Data Found`, but when I delete this:

```
 if(isset($_POST["platforma"]))
 {
  $platforma_filter = implode(',', $_POST["platforma"]);
  $query .= "
   AND id_platformy IN ('{$platforma_filter}')
  ";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["typ"]))
 {
  $typ_filter = implode(',', $_POST["typ"]);
  $query .= "
   AND id_typu IN('{$typ_filter}')
  ";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["zanr"]))
 {
  $zanr_filter = implode(',', $_POST["zanr"]);
  $query .= "
   AND id_zanr IN('{$zanr_filter}')
  ";
 }
```

Then output is all products.

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM produkty WHERE 
 ";
 /*if(isset($_POST["minimum_price"], $_POST["maximum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_price"]))
 {
  $query .= "
   AND cena BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_price"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_price"]."'
  ";
 }    */
 if(isset($_POST["platforma"]))
 {
  $platforma_filter = implode(',', $_POST["platforma"]);
  $query .= "
   AND id_platformy IN ('{$platforma_filter}')
  ";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["typ"]))
 {
  $typ_filter = implode(',', $_POST["typ"]);
  $query .= "
   AND id_typu IN('{$typ_filter}')
  ";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["zanr"]))
 {
  $zanr_filter = implode(',', $_POST["zanr"]);
  $query .= "
   AND id_zanr IN('{$zanr_filter}')
  ";
 }
```

```
<?php

                    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(nazev_platformy),id_platformy FROM Platformy ORDER BY nazev_platformy DESC";
                    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
                    $statement->execute();
                    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand" value="<?php echo $row['id_platformy']; ?>"  > <?php echo $row['nazev_platformy']; ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }

                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

    <div class="list-group">
     <h3>Typ Produktu</h3>
                    <?php

                    $query = "
                    SELECT DISTINCT(nazev_typu),id_typu FROM typ_produktu ORDER BY nazev_typu DESC
                    ";
                    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
                    $statement->execute();
                    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector ram" value="<?php echo $row['id_typu']; ?>" > <?php echo $row['nazev_typu']; ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <?php    
                    }

                    ?>
                </div>

    <div class="list-group">
     <h3>Žánr hry</h3>
     <?php
                    $query = "
                    SELECT DISTINCT(nazev),id_zanr FROM zanr ORDER BY nazev DESC
                    ";
                    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
                    $statement->execute();
                    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector storage" value="<?php echo $row['id_zanr']; ?>"  > <?php echo $row['nazev']; ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">
             <br />
                <div class="row filter_data">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>  
   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
        var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
        var platforma = get_filter('platforma');
        var typ = get_filter('typ');
        var zanr = get_filter('zanr');
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, platforma:platforma, typ:typ, zanr:zanr},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }

    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    $('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:0,
        max:65000,
        values:[0, 65000],
        step:50,
        stop:function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
            filter_data();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Problem is with the way you are using quotes. `'1','2','3'` and `'1,2,3'` are just two massively different things.

Comment: (And that the whole things appears to be massively open to SQL injection, does that still need mentioning …?)